# Redis db, can't put 100000000 records. Get exception

Tags: python, redis

I have 2 cpu linux machine with 8gb of RAM and I try to put 100000000 key:value records like     "int:string(15 characters)"

At about 67000000 records I receive the next exception:

```
Stored 67350000
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting 127.0.0.1:6386. Connection refused.
```

I've tried pipelining, used python rediscluster lib, but the result is same exception. I suspect that I run out of RAM. Is there any way to store this 100000000 ?

More info before crash:

```
Stored 50000 data in 8.69719982147
Stored 67000000
Stored 50000 data in 7.5351691246
Stored 67050000
Stored 50000 data in 6.72475004196
Stored 67100000
Stored 50000 data in 22.6166160107
Stored 67150000
Stored 50000 data in 65.9979310036
Stored 67200000
Stored 50000 data in 206.794868946
Stored 67250000
Stored 50000 data in 610.146175861
Stored 67300000
Stored 50000 data in 1142.35663819
Stored 67350000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redis_test_cluster.py", line 40, in <module>
    r_server.set(str(position_counter), randomword(15))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/rediscluster/cluster_client.py", line 247, in function
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/redis/client.py", line 666, in set
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/redis/client.py", line 364, in execute_command
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/redis/connection.py", line 301, in send_command
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/redis/connection.py", line 283, in send_packed_command
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/redis/connection.py", line 231, in connect
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting 127.0.0.1:6386. Connection refused.
```

Comment: What does Redis' `INFO ALL` say about your memory? What does your server's `free -m` say about its RAM? Re. pipelining - are you sending the commands eventually or just trying to pipeline all records in one go? Note that even with pipelining, you still need to send the batch once it reaches a sane value (e.g. 100) but when to do it depends on the size of data (records) and network considerations.

Comment: As for pipelining I send 50000 when collect them.
When I use cluster, I have 8 nodes. Each of them receive about 8000000 records. Unfortunately I can't tell exact values about memory for that crash moment. I noticed that time of writing into redis increased at the last values

Comment: Certainly looks like your running out of memory, but without more info is hard to be sure. Either increase your memory or optimize your data to store the entire dataset.

Comment: IMO, using pipelining by batch of 50000 is a wrong idea - there is a protection mechanism in Redis which closes the connection if the buffers become too large. I would reduce the size of the batches - start with 1000 items only.